# Data from API showing undefined while storing in a constant in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using node.js. While using API fetch I am unable to store the API value and use it in my app. It is showing undefined after I stored inside a const.

```
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  hostname: 'apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
  port: null,
  path: '/market/v2/get-summary?region=IN',
  headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'hidden/please use a api key from apidojo',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
};

 http.get(options, function (res) {
  const chunks = [];

  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on('end', function () {
    const body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    const allYahoodata=(body.toString());
    const jsonData=(JSON.parse(allYahoodata));
    console.log(typeof jsonData);
    const nseExchangeData=(jsonData.marketSummaryAndSparkResponse.result[1]);
    console.log(typeof nseExchangeData);
    const exchangeName=nseExchangeData.fullExchangeName;
    console.log(typeof exchangeName);
    const exchangeTimeLive=console.log(exchangeName);
    console.log(typeof exchangeTimeLive);
    
  });
});
```

Output:

> Server started at 4000 port
> object
> object
> string
> NSE
> undefined

I am unable to use the undefined value to use somewhere in my page. I am using node.js. When starting my app it is running and it is giving value before I store inside a constant but after it is showing undefined.

Comment: `const exchangeTimeLive = console.log(exchangeName);` is undefined because a `console.log` doesn't return anything so it's normal. Which value are you trying to use ?